# Changing "Private Sub Procedure1" in Form1 to "Public -" (Form1) from Form2

Tags: vba, ms-access

In Form1 Procedure1 is private. I need to change declaration in public from Form2 with VBA.

In Form2 I'm looking for a command  like that:

```
Private Sub Procedure2_Click ()

Form_Form1.Declaration Public

End Sub
```

The previous code will change From1 from

```
Private Sub Procedure1 ()
blablabla
End Sub
```

To

```
Public Sub Procedure1 ()
blablabla
End Sub
```

much appreciated

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It smacks of bad design, and could cause problems by changing the scope of the procedure.

Comment: Thank for commenting. Private sub Procedure1 is among other "old" subs. All of them are private. I supposed none can accidentally use Procedure1.

Comment: Moreover, I need to update many identical files so I'd rather doing it by code and not manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do such a thing. The access modifiers (Private/Public) are static. When you try to call a Private Sub from another object, the code cannot be complied and thus cannot be run. Since such a code cannot be run, there is no way to create a Sub that would change a Private Sub to a Public Sub.

Well, unless you are writing a tool as an add-in that you would call at design time. I once wrote a code formatter like this. But this code cannot be run at the run-time of your application.

Comment: Sorry for my silly question. Can I easly prepare an installation file? I mean installing my updates with an add-in. I don't know if it's feasible. My updates are to following two: changing from private to public procedure1, add a form (with code). Thank for replies.

Comment: Such a tool will be used at design time by a programmer (you). Then the code transformed by the add-in will be compiled and tested and finally shipped. It is not intended to be used by an end-user. I also don't see the point of converting private subs to public in bulk. Most private subs and functions were designed to be private. Note also that this would not be an Access add-in but a VBA add-in as DLL that must be registered via regsvr32 as an administrator.

Comment: Thank you. Ok, I see. I need to update many identical files so I'd rather doing it by code and not manually.